# Change color of text in pop up message box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a message box that pops up to display a message if any field is left blank on a form.
But I want to change the color of the writing to red

```
protected void DisplayMsg(string Msg)
    {
        string script = "<script>$(document).ready(function () {  $(\"<div>" + Msg.Replace("'","").Replace("\"","")+ "</div>\").dialog({modal: true,title: \"NOTE\",buttons: [ { text: \"Ok\", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( \"close\" ); } } ]}); });</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Message", script);
    }
```

How do I change the color of the text?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. You should rewrite your question with only the Javascript. This way people, who do not know C#, can also help find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add style to your div element, like this

```
"<div style='color:red'>" + Msg.Replace("'","").Replace("\"","")+ "</div>\"
```

Comment: This will change the colour of **all** the text within the dialog. A proper solution would be to use the [dialog's events](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) to get at the contents,  and then change it there.